# WebClient Authorization C# x-access-token

Tags: c#, webclient, http-status-code-403, api-key

I try to get json from api (https://www.goldapi.io).
It requires api key to have acces to it.
I have no idea where is a problem. It always shows me 403 forbidden.
It is desctop application - Windows Forms App.

---

```
    public class GetData
    {

        private const string sourceSiteUrlGoldPLN = "https://www.goldapi.io/api/XAU/PLN";
        private const string apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        public string GetGoldValueFromApi(string sourceSiteUrl = sourceSiteUrlGoldPLN)
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                //webClient.Headers["X-ApiKey"] = apiKey;
                webClient.Headers.Add("X-ApiKey",  apiKey);

                string reponse = webClient.DownloadString(sourceSiteUrl);//      <= 403 Forbidden here
                dynamic dobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(reponse);
                var temp = dobj["price"];
                Console.WriteLine(reponse);
            return reponse;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried many combinations with Header properties but nothing works.

Comment: The page you have linked to for the api shows "x-access-token" as the header, not "X-ApiKey"

Comment: Also, a GET request is not sending json so you don't need the Content-Type header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to get json from api (https://www.goldapi.io). It requires api
> key to have acces to it. I have no idea where is a problem. It always
> shows me 403 forbidden

As per https://www.goldapi.io/ API document it requires [x-access-token](https://www.goldapi.io/dashboard) as  request Headers but you are passing X-ApiKey consequently, you are getting 403 error which means authentication request were incorrect. As you can see below:

[image]

Correct Way:

```cs
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                webClient.Headers.Add("x-access-token", apikey);
                string reponse = webClient.DownloadString("https://www.goldapi.io/api/XAU/PLN");
                dynamic dobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(reponse);
                var temp = dobj["price"];
                Console.WriteLine(reponse);
                return Ok(reponse);
            }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will know it in the future.

Comment: Its quite alright and glad to assist you on this.